# How do I extract image from camera intent for path "file:///storage/..." on android

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, camera

I have been trying to get an image from a camera intent. My code is based on the answer to [How to make Android Camera Intent return full size picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000651/how-to-make-android-camera-intent-return-full-size-picture) .

My code for calling the camera is

```
public void dispatchCameraIntent(View view) {
    Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    CameraUtils.cameraImageUri = CameraUtils.getOutputMediaFileUri(this);
    camera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, CameraUtils.cameraImageUri);
    startActivityForResult(camera, TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

The file uri comes back as

```
file:///storage/sdcard0/Pictures/MyCameraApp/IMG_20140322_201346.jpg
```

My problem is that the data field in `onActivityResult` is always null:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
  //data is null
}
```

I have tried few other approaches, but they all fail.

Comment: What is resultCode value?

Comment: @fisher3421 `RESULT_OK`